# Adding key value pair to object inside forEach loop

Tags: foreach, javascript-objects

I'm trying to add a thenable result to an object using a forEach loop. I can see the entries when I console.log the results, but when I try to use them for other parts of my code, I get an empty object.

I was getting an error previously telling me that the object's name (results) was not defined. I moved the object outside of the function and now I just get an empty object returned when I try to return the values of the object.

I tried this first:

```
        let results = {};

        // Check for all videos in cache (returns [])
        const findAllVidsInCache = (videoArray) => {
            videoArray.forEach(video => {
                check(video).then(res => {
                    // resultsArray.push(res);
                    results[video] = res;
                    return results;
                });
            });
            return results;
        }
```

Then I tried this:

```
        let results = {};

        // Check for all videos in cache (returns [])
        const findAllVidsInCache = (videoArray) => {
            videoArray.forEach(video => {
                check(video).then(res => {
                    // resultsArray.push(res);
                    results[video] = res;
                    return results;
                });
            });
            let values = Object.values(results);
            return values;
        }
```

But I still keep getting an empty object when the function is called (I'm using devTools to call the function so nothing else should be interfering with it).

What I'm looking for, and what I can see in the console when I log it to the console, is an object that appears like so:

```
'video1': false,
'video2': false,
'video3': false,
'video4': true,
'video5': false,
...
```

Up to 12 videos.

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: Maybe try not use a const and var instead . 

Constant can change if it is an array type ... however it looks like yours is a function type  which updates with a forEach in the function which means it does not stay constant ...

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try reading about promise handling. `return results;` returns a promise.